# `rspec --configure autotest` throws "uninitialized constant Class::FileUtils"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, autotest

I'm trying to setup autotest with RSpec.  Never had a problem before, but when I run `rspec --configure autotest`, I get the following error/trace:

```
Autotest loads RSpec's Autotest subclass when there is a .rspec file in the project's root directory.
/Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Class::FileUtils (NameError)
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line_configuration.rb:38:in `create_dot_rspec_file'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line_configuration.rb:29:in `generate'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line_configuration.rb:12:in `run'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in parser'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1277:in `call'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1277:in `block in parse_in_order'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1264:in `catch'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1264:in `parse_in_order'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1258:in `order!'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1349:in `permute!'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/optparse.rb:1370:in `parse!'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:18:in `parse!'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/option_parser.rb:4:in `parse!'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:88:in `command_line_options'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:122:in `custom_options_file'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:65:in `parse_options'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `run'
    from /Users/brennon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@timekeepa/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Simply running `rspec` runs just fine, and running `autotest` runs fine as well, but only loads Cucumber features.  Also, `require 'fileutils'` returns true in irb.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, and it seems like this can't be the correct solution, but deleting and recreating the `.rspec` file solved the problem.